# Pandas: group by two columns, sum up the first value in the first column group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, head

In Python, I have a pandas data frame `df`.

```
ID    Ref    Dist
 A      0      10
 A      0      10
 A      1      20
 A      1      20
 A      2      30     
 A      2      30
 A      3       5
 A      3       5
 B      0       8
 B      0       8
 B      1      40
 B      1      40
 B      2       7
 B      2       7
```

I want to group by `ID` and `Ref`, and take the first row of the `Dist` column in each group.

```
ID    Ref    Dist
 A      0      10
 A      1      20
 A      2      30     
 A      3       5
 B      0       8
 B      1      40
 B      2       7
```

And I want to sum up the `Dist` column in each `ID` group.

```
ID     Sum
 A      65
 B      55
```

I tried this to do the first step, but this gives me just an index of the row and `Dist`, so I cannot move on to the second step.

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Ref'])['Dist'].head(1)
```

It'd be wonderful if somebody helps me for this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

The first step you need to use `first` since you want the first in the `groupby`. Once you've done that, use `reset_index()` so you can use a `groupby` afterwards and sum it up using `ID`.

```
df.groupby(['ID','Ref'])['Dist'].first()\
          .reset_index().groupby(['ID'])['Dist'].sum()
ID
A    65
B    55
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `drop_duplicates` before the `groupby`. The default behavior is to keep the first duplicate row, which is what you want.

```
df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Ref']).groupby('ID').Dist.sum()
#A    65
#B    55
#Name: Dist, dtype: int64
```